# How to install ffmpeg in Linux Mint Rosa using aptitude?

Tags: software-installation, repository, ffmpeg

I want to install `ffmpeg` in Linux Mint Rosa. There is a [tutorial](https://www.aptgetlife.co.uk/installing-ffmpeg-on-linux-mint-17-3/) to do this using `apt`, but I would like to know how to do this with `aptitude` instead, since it is the command I am most familiar with.

Just to summarize everything here, the procedure described in the tutorial is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: ffmpeg is already a part of Linux Mint, don't use external repositories!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Ipor Sircer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/182562/ipor-sircer), `ffmpeg` is available from the default Mint repositories, and I recommend trying that first.

To answer your question, in most cases you can simply replace `apt-get` with `aptitude`:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install ffmpeg
```

If you do end up wanting the third-party repository, use the given `add-apt-repository` command without changing it.